# Scroll to a specific location using only Javascript when scrollTop() is not working?

Tags: javascript

So my problem is a bit specific.

The first thing is that due to something (I don't know what) the result of any element of the page `.scrollTop` equal 0

This makes the use of `scrollTop()` impossible.

However I can use `scrollIntoView()` BUT I need to add a specific height to my element.

Something like `document.getElementById(ELEMENT).scrollIntoView() + 50px`.

So I wanted to know what does `scrollIntoView()` takes in account (since its not scrollTop) and if I could edit this value to manage what I want?

Or maybe you do have an other solution for me?

Edit: This is the page I'm trying to scroll in https://www.naissance.fr/prenoms/ and this is the bloc I want to scroll to (without the navigator over it) : `document.getElementsByClassName('mastcontainer__body')[0].scrollIntoView(true);`

Comment: Can you show the code where scrollTop is not working, surely it would be better to get to the bottom of that rather than hacking up some other solution?

Comment: Add a link to your page, we can find why `.scrollTop` is 0.

Comment: @Pete I've edited

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you have been looking for,

To get the position of any element in page, you can use 'getBoundingClientRect' method like this, and window.scrollTo() to scroll to that particular location.

```
     var htmlElement = document.getElementById('container');
     var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect()
     window.scrollTo(elementPosition.top, elementPosition.left)
```

Also refer this link for more learning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Interesting answer. I'll keep the part about `getBoudingClientRect()` however as specified in the title I can't use `scrollTo()`